# NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED issue in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am facing issues with chrome browser (NET::ERR_CERT_REVOKED ).
I use GoDaddy SSL certificate. It works fine with the Firefox browser.
couple of my colleagues are able to access the URL fine. Please help me in finding the root cause of it. I tried some many ways to resolve it but couldn't find the solution.
[Error while accessing web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkv5O.png)

Comment: Image :https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkv5O.png

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I have the same issue on Google Chrome.. Still dont fix it.

Comment: I found a workaround for it. I generated a new certificate on one server and I copied the same keystore for all the servers.

Answer (score 9):

Type *thisisunsafe* while on the page (not in the address bar) and this will whitelist the page.

Just for context, I'm using this workaround for cluster nodes that I know to be legitimate self-signed certs. There is a reason why Chrome rejects such certificate errors.

Comment: I am working as an engineer for years but this made me feel like a "hacker" in a very long time. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few days ago (I am also using GoDaddy). Some browsers display this warning and some don't because the way they check certificate revocation is different (CRL or OCSP).

Long story short, a **temporary fix** is that disabling certificate revocation. It fixes the issue for THAT client only. Other clients continue to have this warning.

To disable certificate revocation check in Internet Explorer:

1. Open **Internet Explorer**
2. In the **Tools** menu, select **Internet Options**
3. Go to the **Advanced** tab. Scroll down to the **Security** section
4. Uncheck **Check for server certificate revocation** option
5. Click **OK**

[image]

([Source](https://port135.com/2019/02/09/error_internet_sec_cert_revoked/))

**The permanent fix** is solving the certificate issue in your server or hosting provider. In my case, I forgot to install the certificate for each of my sites hosted in GoDaddy. I thought UCC certificates are automatically installed but appearantly, they don't. Follow [these instructions](https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-a-ucc-certificate-for-cpanel-addon-domains-9089?) to install UCC certificate to your GoDaddy websites.

Answer (score 0):

I also made lots of research but here is the solution:

```
start - run - cmd
```

type:

```
certutil –urlcache * delete
```

all done.